# C# Is it possible to edit delegate parameters for WPF button_click events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, delegates

This is probably a REALLY dumb question, but on the upside I don't think anyone's asked it here before(?)

The default number of parameters in all the button_clicked subscriber methods is two:

```
(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I recently read that the arguments for the event are defined within the delegate. Now is this just one delegate for each button_clicked event? Or does each button have it's own separate delegate? I'm not explaining myself very well here...

Say I want to pass in three arguments into a single subscriber method instead of the above TWO, I've just had some simple code auto-generated for me after double clicking my button in designer view. Where is the class that that method subscribes to? Is there a way I can edit it's delegate and add in another parameter?

The reason I'm asking this WAS that I thought there could be a way to pass a variable to another class - into it's subscriber method. Unfortunately that subscriber method only takes two arguments. So I'm now looking for ways to easily pass in my variable, and this was a 'back-of-the-mind' sort of solution.

Comment: Where would the value for that parameter come from and how would the button know how to pass it?

Comment: you can set the `Tag` property of the button and then get it in the event handler. Where does your parameter come from, xaml or code?

Comment: the delegates for form element are in the frameworks libraries, you can't change those. What you need is probably VERY simply, but you have to show some code and maybe explain what  exactly should happen. then someone can help you

Comment: you can use global variables except of passing local variables

Comment: Because this is WPF you should look into using the command of the button in combination with the commandparameter.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah I quickly realized that this would be an issue, but still wanted to ask where button delegates are. :)

Comment: @x4rf41 Okay. Here's what's up. I'm using the NAudio class library to get all the audio devices on my system. This functionality is specific to its own window, allowing you to choose which device you want. I have a list: List<WaveInCapabilities> sources = new List<WaveInCapabilities>(); which holds all the info. Including the DEVICENUMBER. This is an int, and that's the variable I want to use that variable in another class. I want to pass it into an event subscriber method, but can't figure out how.

Comment: @x4rf41 So I was looking for ways to pass in my variable, and had the fleeting idea of trying to pass it in by editing the button's delegate and adding in a parameter for my variable. This is obviously a really silly idea and I knew that when posting, hence the disclaimer. However, I was curious as to whether editing a button's delegate might be possible and how such things are laid out in the framework. So I posted this question anyway. Glad I did too because you've just told me that my idea is really a very bad one. Thank you. :)

Comment: No, I did not tell you that the idea is a bad one. I will agree that changing the delegate is in fact impossible but I still asked a question: How would the button know which value to pass (where would the value come from)? The answer by @thumbmunkeys has one way where, although you don't actually change the delegate, you can still obtain more information about something in the event handler. So again, how would the button know which value to pass / where would the value come from?

Comment: @user3752329 so you basically have a sort of dialog where someone can choose the audio device, and on clicking "ok" or something you want to pass it to another form  ( the class that opened the window for the device selection)

Comment: @x4rf41 yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guys are waaaayy overthinking this :). Simply use a lamda and you can redefine any delegate however you want:

```
theButton.Click += (x, y) => myHandler(someRandomParam1, someRandomParam2, someRandomParam3, someRandomParam4, ... someRandomParam73);
```

It's *that* simple.

Comment: yes they do https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Tag` parameter of the button and then retrieve it in the handler.

If the button is defined in XAML:

If the button is defined in code:

```
var button  = new Button() {Tag = "Hi"};
```

Then in the event handler:

```
public void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // this will give you the string "Hi"
   string hi = (string)((Button)sender).Tag;
}
```